# Laravel: master view or controller always called

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

How can I set a "default" view and/or controller so it will be **always called** no matter the route?

I have tried with:
(**routes.php**)

```
Route::get('/*', function(){
  return View::make('master');
});
```

and:

```
Route::get('*', function(){
      return View::make('master');
    });
```

But gives me *NotFoundHttpException*;

**Related question**: Is there a better way to do this than setting it in the routes.php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have something called [Controller Layouts](http://laravel.com/docs/templates), then in your controller you can create a variable named `$layout` and set it to a master or default view:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $layout = 'layout.master';

    public function getIndex() {

        $data[];

        $this->layout->content = View::make('myview', $data);
    }
```

Now in the layout.master view you can access the `$content` variable.